# IsNull() sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, isnull

I am attempting increment the value of a column field named "Number" by 1, and if the value is currently Null I would like to set the value to 1 because a Null value cannot be incremented. I discovered the isNull() function and do not get the results using the following statement:

```
Update SomeTable set Number = IsNull(Number, Number+ 1) where
ItemCode = '000000' ;
```

My question is basically how to simultaneously update a field value by the increment of 1 and set the value to 1 if it is currently "NULL"

Thanks!

Comment: `IsNull(Number,0) + 1`

Comment: @Lamak - I understood the mistake ;)

Comment: @Prdp In fact, both of you did :)

Comment: @Lamak: Thanks for your feedback ;)

Comment: Actually, some people are giving advise on how to change zero(0) to 1 too even though OP didn´t ask for it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `Number` from second parameter of `ISNULL` function.

> Anything + NULL = NULL

so make the `ISNULL` to result `0` when it is `NULL` and then add `1` to the result

```
Update SomeTable set Number = IsNull(Number, 0) + 1 where
ItemCode = '000000' ;
```

or

```
Update SomeTable set Number = IsNull(Number+1, 1) where
ItemCode = '000000' ;
```

or two different updates (not recommended)

```
Update SomeTable set Number = Number + 1 where
ItemCode = '000000' AND Number IS NOT NULL;

Update SomeTable set Number = 1 where
ItemCode = '000000' AND Number IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` function choose the alternative value if the main value is null.

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET Number =
CASE
    WHEN Number IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Number + 1
END 
WHERE ItemCode = '000000' ;
```

Or

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET Number = ISNULL(Number, 0) + 1
WHERE ItemCode = '000000' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `WHERE ItemCode = '000000';` will update all records with this item code: `000000`. A simple `update SomeTable set Number = 1` will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use `coalesce` to provide a default value of 0 when NULL is found, as in

```
Update SomeTable 
   set Number = coalesce(number,0) + 1
 where ItemCode = '000000' ;
```